# node Request-promis-native never return to then or catch sections in type script

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, node-request

Request promise never returns to then or catch sections in typescript. The data was POSTed to the server correctly but the response from the server is not returned in the promise then or catch sections. I tried with async/await but still have the same issue.

Below Code is run on AWS Lambda Node 8.10, This happens only when I use OAuth in Header.

Node 8.11.1

```
import * as  request from 'request-promise-native';

            const httpParams = {
                uri: this.config.restBaseURL,
                qs: endPoint,
                method: 'POST',
                body: data,
                json: true,
                headers: headers,
                oauth: oAuth
            };

request(httpParams).then(res => {
                return res;
            }).catch(err => {
                throw err;
            });


"request": "^2.81.0",
"request-promise-native": "^1.0.5",
```